# Is there a need to pass variable by reference in php5?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

With PHP5 using "copy on write" and passing by reference causing more of a performance penalty than a gain, why should I use pass-by-reference?  Other than call-back functions that would return more than one value or classes who's attributes you want to be alterable without calling a set function later(bad practice, I know), is there a use for it that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use pass-by-reference when you want to modify the result and that's all there is to it.

Remember as well that in PHP objects are **always** pass-by-reference.

Personally I find PHP's system of copying values implicitly (I guess to defend against accidental modification) cumbersome and unintuitive but then again I started in strongly typed languages, which probably explains that. But I find it interesting that objects differ from PHP's normal operation and I take it as evidence that PHP"s implicit copying mechanism really isn't a good system.

Comment: Java's behavior is identical to PHP's (objects passed by reference, primitives passed ["copied"] by value), as is, I believe, C++'s.  Which strongly typed languages were you referring to?

Comment: Java does *not* pass objects by reference; it copies the value of an object reference; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference.

Comment: Fair enough.  Based on laurentb's example below, it looks like you could say the same about PHP, which only reinforces my point: the way arguments are passed in PHP and Java are nearly indistinguishable.  I'm still waiting for an example of a "strongly typed language" that copies objects passed as arguments outright.

Comment: @FrankFarmer: the thing is, in both Java and PHP 5, objects are not values. When you create a new object, you get an *object reference*. If you look at a language where you can have objects as values and has pass by value, e.g. C++, then when you pass objects it copies them

Answer (score 2):

A recursive function that fills an array? Remember writing something like that, once.

There's no point in having hundreds of copies of a partially filled array and copying, splicing and joining parts at every turn.

Answer (score 0):

Even when passing objects there is a difference.

Try this example:

```
class Penguin { }

$a = new Penguin();

function one($a)
{
  $a = null;
}

function two(&$a)
{
  $a = null;
}

var_dump($a);
one($a);
var_dump($a);
two($a);
var_dump($a);
```

The result will be:

```
object(Penguin)#1 (0) {}
object(Penguin)#1 (0) {}
NULL
```

When you pass a variable containing a reference to an object by reference, you are able to modify the reference to the object.